# How mobile phone calls process?

Tags: telephony

this may be a noob question, but I'm having a hard time finding the answer. How does a mobile phone call work in the mobile phone itself so that analog data (voice) is transmitted out of the mobile phone through the antenna ?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts (end-devices) are off-topic here. You could try to ask on [electronics.se].

Answer (score 1):

A very broad question, so a very broad answer.

The signal from the microphone is sent through an analog-to-digital converter, compressed using a (lossy) codec, the digital data is packetized and then sent over the cellular network.

How that *exactly* works depends on the kind of voice service and the kind of mobile network. The details easily fill several books.